# List all mounted Volumes in a Menu Bar Submenu (programmatically only)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, menubar

I'm currently working on a "menu bar only" project and I need to list all mounted Volumes in a submenu in the menubar app. I figured out how to print() all mounted volumes but I need help with the submenu (without .xib or .storyboard work)
This is my "listVolumes func"

```
    func listVolumes(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let keys = [NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey]
    let paths = NSFileManager().mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(keys, options: [])
    if let urls = paths {
        for url in urls {
            if let components = url.pathComponents
                where components.count > 1
                    && components[1] == "Volumes" {
                print(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

an below is my code for the "menu bar app"

```
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-2)

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named: "StatusBarButtonImage")
    }
    let menu = NSMenu()

    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Volumes", action: Selector("volumes:"), keyEquivalent: ""))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separatorItem())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Help", action: Selector("help:"), keyEquivalent: ""))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separatorItem())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: Selector("terminate:"), keyEquivalent: "q"))

    statusItem.menu = menu

}
```

so my question is, how can I create a submenu that contains all the mounted drives (programmatically only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a submenu to the `volumes` menu item for example

```
let volumesMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Volumes", action: Selector("volumes:"), keyEquivalent: "")
menu.addItem(volumesMenuItem)
let volumesMenu = NSMenu(title: "Volumes")
volumesMenuItem.submenu = volumesMenu
```

I recommend to return an array of the names from your `listVolumes()` function, then you can add menu items to `volumesMenu` assuming `volumes` contains the names

```
for volumeName in volumes {
    volumesMenu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: volumeName, action: Selector("selectVolume"), keyEquivalent: ""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but talking about the array, when I use it I get the error "Type (NSMenuItem) -> () does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Comment: I placed the for in array directly over the 'let volumesMenuItem' line

Comment: You can't return anything from a method specified in the target/action pattern. Redesign the workflow for example to create the menu items in the `listVolumes` function. Then you need a property for the submenu reference.

Comment: sorry for asking so late but could 'Answer This Question' again with the redesigned workflow? Wasn't able to get that to work